# How to understand the difference between Offset and VirAddr in Program Headers in elf?

Tags: elf, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading, readelf

There is a shared library elf file, I use `readelf -l` to see the program headers, the output is:

```
Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x0
There are 11 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x00000034 0x00000034 0x00100 0x00100 R   0x4
  INTERP         0x000194 0x00000194 0x00000194 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /system/bin/linker]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x3aa8c4 0x3aa8c4 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x3ab1cc 0x003ac1cc 0x003ac1cc 0x062c0 0x25ee4 RW  0x1000
  LOAD           0x3b2000 0x003d3000 0x003d3000 0x02561 0x02561 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x3b4e8c 0x003d6e8c 0x003d6e8c 0x00298 0x00299 RW  0x1000
  LOAD           0x3b5268 0x003d8268 0x003d8268 0x00128 0x00128 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x3b5268 0x003d8268 0x003d8268 0x00128 0x00128 RW  0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0
  EXIDX          0x2e71e8 0x002e71e8 0x002e71e8 0x0b558 0x0b558 R   0x4
  GNU_RELRO      0x3ab1cc 0x003ac1cc 0x003ac1cc 0x01e34 0x01e34 RW  0x4

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .dynsym .dynstr .hash .gnu.version .gnu.version_d .rel.dyn .plt .text .ARM.extab .ARM.exidx .rodata 
   03     .data.rel.ro.local .fini_array .data.rel.ro .got .data .bss 
   04     .rel.plt 
   05     .init_array 
   06     .dynamic 
   07     .dynamic 
   08     
   09     .ARM.exidx 
   10     .data.rel.ro.local .fini_array .data.rel.ro .got
```

if the following struct represents an program header:

```
   typedef struct {
       uint32_t   p_type;
       Elf32_Off  p_offset;
       Elf32_Addr p_vaddr;
       Elf32_Addr p_paddr;
       uint32_t   p_filesz;
       uint32_t   p_memsz;
       uint32_t   p_flags;
       uint32_t   p_align;
   } Elf32_Phdr;
```

Then my question is: How to understand the difference between `p_offset` and `p_vaddr` which corresponds to `Offset` and `VirtAddr` in output of `readelf -l`? Will them always be the same? And will them be changed by the procedure of dynamic loading?

Comment: `p_offset` - offset in file, `p_vaddr` - address of section after loaded to memory (say, after c runtime initialization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking-

`p_offset` - offset within the elf file

`p_vaddr` - address of section after loaded to memory (say, after c runtime initialization finished)

They will not always be the same, those addresses can be configured using linker script for example. [Refer to this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/sections.html).

As for the shared library addresses after library loaded into a process address space - this depends on process addresses space, ASLR, and more, but its safe to say that the dynamic loader will set new addresses (`p_vaddr`, aka execution address)

Answer (score 4):

> How to understand the difference between p_offset and p_vaddr which corresponds to Offset and VirtAddr in output of readelf -l?

The runtime loader will `mmap` a set of pages at offset `.p_offset` (rounded down to pagesize) at virtual address `.p_vaddr` (similarly rounded down; that address will actually have some large multiple-page offset added to it for `ET_DYN` object).

> Will them always be the same?

They *aren't* the same even in your example:

```
LOAD           0x3ab1cc 0x003ac1cc
```

`0x3ab1` != `0x3ac1`. What *is* guaranteed is that `.p_offset % pagesize == .p_vaddr % pagesize` (otherwise `mmap` will become impossible).